# отсутствует ветка master

Tags: git, git-branch

пишу команды

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin //our repo
$ git fetch origin
$ git branch -a
  remotes/origin/new-design
  remotes/origin/new-develop
  remotes/origin/new-master
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

в итоге создается ветка `new-master`, а должна быть `master`.
что тут не так?

Comment: может быть у Вас new-master это дефолтная ветка? Но таким странным образом я ещё не видел, чтобы делали clone.

Comment: как проверить дефолтная или нет? и как вообще сделать это нормально чтобы с master было

Comment: после `$ git fetch origin` выполните команду `$ git branch -a` и приложите к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit])

Comment: сделал, результат приложил

Comment: На удаленном сервере так называются ветки. Это вопрос к тем, кто их так назвал. Но никто не мешает сделать `git checkout new-master && git branch master && git push -u origin master`

Comment: выполнил эти 3 команды вместе, потом проверил git branch -a, ничего не изменилось. дело в том что надо чтобы было вместо new-master - master, эти команды решат вопрос?

Comment: первая команда получает нужную ветку, вторая на базе нее создает master, третья - пушит все на сервер.

Answer (score 1):

в удалённом хранилище присутствуют три указателя («ветки» в терминологии программы *git*): `new-design`, `new-develop` и `new-master`.

указателя с именем `master`, согласно приведённой вами информации, в нём нет.

если вы хотите, чтобы в вашей локальной копии хранилища был ещё и указатель `master`, «привязанный» («tracking») к указателю `new-branch` в удалённом хранилище, после упомянутых вами команд `init`, `remote` и `fetch` вам надо выполнить, например, такую команду (приведён и пример её вывода):

```
$ git checkout -t -b master origin/new-master 
Branch master set up to track remote branch new-master from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'master'
```

---

если же вы хотите, наоборот, чтобы в удалённом хранилище появился указатель `master` (указывающий, например, на тот же коммит, что и сущуствующий указатель `new-master`), то после упомянутых вами команд `init`, `remote` и `fetch` вам надо выполнить, например, такие команды (приведён и пример их вывода):

```
$ git checkout new-master 
Branch new-master set up to track remote branch new-master from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'new-master'
$ git checkout -b master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
$ git push origin master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To url-удалённого-хранилища
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```